# R how to add another column to a dataset based on 2 other columns

Tags: r, dplyr, switch-statement

I have a data set of messages exchanged in an organization, I want to create another column based on `case_when` the `sender_department == receiver_department`, assign `"intra"` while if the `sender_department != receiver_department`, assign `"inter"`.

I'm doing this to know the proportion of inter and intra departmental messages over the period.

I've use the code below

```
intra_inter_msg <- DF %>%
  mutate(inter_intra = case_when(sender_department == receiver_department, ~"intra",         ,
                                 sender_department != receiver_department, ~"inter"))
```

and I got this error

> Error in `mutate()`:
> ! Problem while computing `inter_intra = case_when(...)`.
> Caused by error in `case_when()`:
> ! Case 1 (`sender_department == receiver_department`) must be a two-sided formula, not a logical

Comment: Just remove the commas before each `~`. I have voted to close as simple typo.

Comment: adding to @RuiBarradas, you haven an extra comma after way after intra: "intra",         ,

Comment: @RenéMartínez Yes, I missed that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I made a little example DF to test it:

```
require(dplyr)
DF = data.frame (sender_department = c("econ","math","history"),receiver_department = c("econ","history","math"))
DF
intra_inter_msg <- DF %>%
  mutate(inter_intra = case_when(sender_department == receiver_department ~"intra",         
                                 sender_department != receiver_department ~"inter"))
intra_inter_msg
```